# How to split a string x.*y into x and y in java?

Tags: java

I have a string `x.*y` and it should be splitted as `x` and `y`.

So, how to do it ?

```
x.*y => [x,y]
```

**Note:** I need x,y into 2 different strings.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Share your tries please ;)

Comment: `s.substring(0, 1)` and `s.substring(3)`?

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet is:

```
String[] splitString = "x.*y".split("\\.\\*");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString));
```

Output from this snippet is:

> [x, y]

The `split` method of `String` takes a regular expression as argument. Since `.` and `*` have special meanings in regular expressions, we need to escape each with a backslash, `\` . And since `\` has a special meaning in a Java string literal, it too has to be escaped with `\`, making `\\` each time.

**Edit:** Since all the escapes make the regular expression a pain to read, I actually recommend this variant:

```
String[] splitString = "x.*y".split(Pattern.quote(".*"));
```

The result is the same. The `quote` method returns a regular expression that matches the argument literally. In this case `\Q.*\E` is returned, where `\Q` and `\E` denote the begin and end of literal quotation.

Comment: Hard to not answer when the OP made no effort :roll_eyes:

Comment: Yes, @azro, I realize I’m somehow spoiling it and risk attracting more unresearched “please write my code for me” type of questions. Sorry. My thought was that this contained enough tricky points and required enough explanation that I could easily imagine that the questioner had made more than one unsuccessful attempt that she or he just forgot to tell us about. So my heart carried me away this once.

Comment: Got the same dilema twice a day so .. just telling but no wickedness :D

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using split, but making use of indexOf method to make subsstrings:

```
  String stringToSplit="your.*string";
  String s1=stringToSplit.substring(0,stringToSplit.indexOf('.'));
  String s2=stringToSplit.substring(stringToSplit.indexOf('*')+1);
```

Comment: It’s an option. If we know that `.` and `*` come right after each other, why not `stringToSplit.indexOf(".*")`?

Comment: That would be better solution.